# App has very high memory usage on initial start but drops to 1/10th usage if its coming from background state

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management

I am facing a memory management issue with my app. The issue i am facing is that, on launching the app, even at the home screen the memory usage is nearly 240mb, this includes a background image, 3-4 banner images and a few other images + their data in arrays.
[image: This is the First Screen]

I checked for memory leaks and found 640bytes of memory leak having no info about it whatsoever.

But on pressing the home button, the app goes to background state with a memory usage of 8mb (which is normal)
[image: This is the Second Screen]

But on coming back to the app, app only uses 22mb.
[image: This is the Second Screen]

It never goes beyond 84mb even while using google-maps inside the app after this point. But if i tried opening that page with google maps, my usage would hit 300mb.

This is the memory usage graph
[image]
I checked for possible memory leaks and found less than 2kb worth memory leaks.

Can someone please guide me on this? If it's possible to make the app use only 22mb from the initial start? And why is there a huge memory usage on initial start but very very low usage after that? Is it because of having images on home screen?

Regards.

Comment: One of the reason can be : You are loading too much data on launch. Check code in "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" & your RootViewController.

Comment: @SharmaVishal I will check and get back to you.

Comment: @SharmaVishal I found it out. It was because i was loading a 5.5mb and 408kb image on my login screen and splash screen. These images were the ones taking all the memory space ! (hard realisation that 5.5mb image was doing all the damage). Changed them and now the app sits comfortably at 13mb. Thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: Glad o help you man. May I put it as answer? It may help others.

Comment: @SharmaVishal Yea go ahead.

Comment: Please check my answer. Upvote & accept it if you find your solution by it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your app is eating too much memory on launch,
It seems like there is some heavy loaded functions or data is operating on launch of app.

Good way to check your code on :

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?)
```

And code inside your RootViewController.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use Xcode->Open Developer Tools->Instruments->Allocations, to see what is consuming memory in your app
2. Another option is to use Memory Graph to see current allocations and find classes/structs/data that wasn't released. I found it super useful for finding strong reference cycles.

[image]

[image]